# Is there an easy way to comment out / silence a code cell in Python/Colab?

Tags: python, comments, simplify, skip

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO4TU.png)
I am wondering if there is an easier way to do exactly this. I often have code that is theoretically useful for later if I run into a problem, but currently do not want it to run. Is there something I can type at the top of the cell like skip to get it to ignore the cell completely?

Comment: You can use a docstring to "comment it out", so surrounding the block with `'''`. As far as I'm aware Python doesn't support block comments.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

you could copy paste the code where it would be useful but i think that it would be better if you made it a function you could call it at will and the code will not run until called on.

```
def yourfunctionnamehere():
  yourcode
```

this is how you create a function

Comment: Honestly also a good approach seeing as it might be used again later on.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).